# C# is generic type with generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Let's asume an interface

```
interface IOwnedBy<T> where T : IOwner 
{ 
    T Owner { get; }
}
```

and

```
interface IOwner 
{ 
    public int Id { get; } 
}
```

Somewhere in my code, I would like to do the following:

```
if (obj is OwnedBy<IOwner>) 
{
    DoSomethingWith( obj.Owner.Id );
}
```

Basically, I want to check whether obj is any OwnedBy implementation. As IOwner is the type constraint of any generic parameter, I thought this one would work. But the condition is never met.

Any way without using alot of reflection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the interface to be covariant in `T`:

```
interface IOwnedBy<out T> where T : IOwner 
{ 
    T Owner { get; }
}
```

`obj is OwnedBy<IOwner>` fails because the compiler can't know if its *safe*; `IOwnedBy` is declared as invariant. If you explicitly tell the compiler that it is covariant, it then *knows* that the conversion is safe and it will work.

And why is it unsafe in a invariant interface? Consider the following:

```
interface IOwnedBy<T> where T : IOwner 
{ 
    T Owner { get; }
    void SetOwner(T Owner);
}

class Person: IOwner { }
class Cat: IOwner { }

Cat tom = ...

IOwnedBy<Person> owned = ...
var nope = owned as IOwnedBy<IOwner>;
nope.SetOwner(tom); //Ouch! Just set a cat as an owner of a IOwnedBy<Person>
```

Comment: I was just writing this exact answer, and was working on a live example - you may as well include it if you want. No Point duplicating your answer. http://rextester.com/BRT23576

Comment: Thank you both, great explanation and example!